# How to crop an image with VBA to a specific form e.g. circle in PowerPoint?

Tags: vba, crop, shapes, powerpoint

I would like to crop a square image shape in PowerPoint with VBA to a specific form e.g. a circle.

With Shape.PictureFormat there are only these options:

- .CropBottom
- .CropLeft
- .CropRight
- .CropTop

Can someone help me with this question?

Thanks!

Moe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Microsoft Community](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-powerpoint/powerpoint-vba-syntax-for-crop-to-shape/0debc1bf-56bb-49c2-8b6f-a18080aca95d?db=5) - you can use [`Shape.AutoShapeType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/powerpoint-vba/articles/shape-autoshapetype-property-powerpoint) to "crop to shape."

```
Sub CropToCircle()
    Dim shp As Shape
    Set shp = ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes(1)

    If shp.Type = msoLinkedPicture Or shp.Type = msoPicture Then
        shp.AutoShapeType = msoShapeOval
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks ... this solved a completely different problem for me. I had some code that sets the amount of rounding on rounded rectangles but wanted to make set all rectangles to the same amount of rounding. Unfortunately, you can't set rounding on regular rectangles. But this pointed me at a simple way of changing regular rectangles to rounded ones and bingo, problem solved.