# Apply a "Crop to Shape" in PowerPoint VBA

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I am trying to take a picture I dynamic load in PowerPoint using VBA.  I do not see any access to allow for cropping to shape.  Has anyone been able to accomplish it.

Use Case
1) Load image dynamically from disk
2) Size image appropriate
3) Apply a Rounded Corner Crop to the picture

Comment: Maybe (probably) helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51436712/how-to-crop-an-image-with-vba-to-a-specific-form-e-g-circle-in-powerpoint

Comment: that worked perfect